# Cannot access a disposed object: System.Threading.ManualResetEvent

Tags: c#, .net, f#, mono

I have a small application which starts up several `async` workflows that read from and write to Kafka topics.  When I start up more than 3 or 4 of these async processes I get the following error:

```
System.ObjectDisposedException: Cannot access a disposed object.
Object name: 'System.Threading.ManualResetEvent'.
```

I can't figure out what's causing this exception to get thrown or what resource is actually triggering it.  I do not use a ManualResetEvent anywhere in my code.  The program works for 3 or for async tasks but when I try more the exception is thrown so it's not consistent as to what triggers it.  There is also nothing to point to where in my code the exception is coming from.

This is the code used to create my async task:

```
let service name readsFrom writeTo (delay:int) =
let producer = createKafkaProducer name
let subscription = createKafkaSubscriber name readsFrom
async{
    printfn "Starting %s" name
    try
        subscription |> Seq.iter
            (fun m -> 
                try
                    let e = m.Message
                    // biz logic
                    producer.Send(new Kafka.Client.Producers.KeyedMessage<string,string>(t, message))
                    Thread.Sleep 500 
                 with
                 | e -> printfn "%s" (e.Message))
      with
      | e -> printfn "%s" (e.Message)}
```

The stack trace for the exception is as follows, event with try/catch blocks around all of the async logic this is all I am able to get.  I believe that this may be an issue with the jroland Kafka client library I am using:

```
Unhandled Exception:
System.ObjectDisposedException: Cannot access a disposed object.
Object name: 'System.Threading.ManualResetEvent'.
  at System.Threading.WaitHandle.CheckDisposed () <0x7fac94651690 + 0x00050> in <filename unknown>:0
  at System.Threading.EventWaitHandle.Set () <0x7fac9464b490 + 0x0003a> in <filename unknown>:0
  at (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) System.Threading.EventWaitHandle:Set ()
  at System.Net.Sockets.SocketAsyncResult.set_IsCompleted (Boolean value) <0x414118b0 + 0x00112> in <filename unknown>:0
  at System.Net.Sockets.SocketAsyncResult.Complete () <0x414114a0 + 0x000df> in <filename unknown>:0
  at System.Net.Sockets.SocketAsyncResult.Complete (System.Exception e) <0x41411420 + 0x0004b> in <filename unknown>:0
  at System.Net.Sockets.SocketAsyncWorker.Connect () <0x41410d80 + 0x003eb> in <filename unknown>:0
  at System.Net.Sockets.SocketAsyncWorker.DispatcherCB (System.Net.Sockets.SocketAsyncResult sar) <0x41410ab0 + 0x000af> in <filename unknown>:0
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.AsyncResult:Invoke (System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.AsyncResult)
  at System.Net.Sockets.SocketAsyncResult.System.Threading.IThreadPoolWorkItem.ExecuteWorkItem () <0x41410760 + 0x00024> in <filename unknown>:0
  at System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch () <0x7fac944b3e50 + 0x001d6> in <filename unknown>:0
  at System.Threading._ThreadPoolWaitCallback.PerformWaitCallback () <0x7fac944b56c0 + 0x00008> in <filename unknown>:0
```

This behavior would seem to violate my understanding of how closures work within .Net.  Because the object is used within a lambda, shouldn't it be effectively captured within the closure and kept alive until the lambda is disposed of?

Comment: That error means that the object is used outside its original scope (see all the other examples on SO). In this case, chances are the `producer` or `subscription` objects have been disposed by the time the async is actually used. Some random ideas: try constructing them inside the async, or perhaps do something like `subscription |> Seq.toList |> Seq.iter` to load the data early. You'll have to play around a bit. Also, the `async` computation expression doesn't seem to be needed as I don't see anything async in it. You might be able to get rid of it all together?

Comment: If it were the `producer` or `subscription` objects that are being disposed of, then why is the error stating `ManualResetEvent`?  The original version of my code had them being constructed within the `async` and the exception could still be created.

Comment: What's the stack trace in the exception? (pluse InnerExceptions, if any)

Comment: Also post the code where the manualresetevent is created, used and disposed.

Comment: Something unexpected happened to that Socket, it was closed or disposed.  This is not terribly unusual of course, it is in general the only way to cancel an asynchronous connect or read attempt.  That the stack trace shows an attempt to Connect() but your code gives no hint that anything is being connected to is a bit Kafkaesque perhaps.

Comment: @HansPassant  that would make sense.  The poor error messaging was making it difficult to figure out, but the Kafka libraries for .Net aren't very well supported.  I also find it odd that when I spin up several client connections, one failing causes everything to fail.